# C# reflection doesn't work with Point class?

Tags: c#, reflection, properties, point

I can't figure out what I am doing wrong. I've got this code:

```
Point p = new Point();
//point is (0,0)
p.X = 50;
//point is (50,0)
PropertyInfo temp = p.GetType().GetProperty("X");
temp.SetValue(p, 100, null);
//and point is still (50,0)
MethodInfo tt = temp.GetSetMethod();
tt.Invoke(p, new object[] { 200 });
//still (50,0)
```

Why?

I was looking for answer, but I have found nothing.

Comment: I knew it would be something almost obvious. Thanks you very much guys.

Answer (score 6):

Ah, the joys of mutable structs. As Sergey said, `Point` is a struct. When you're calling `PropertyInfo.SetValue`, you're taking the value of `p`, boxing it (which copies the value), modifying the contents of the box... but then ignoring it.

You *can* still use reflection with it - but importantly, you only want to box it *once*. So this works:

```
object boxed = p;
PropertyInfo temp = p.GetType().GetProperty("X");
temp.SetValue(boxed, 100, null);
Console.WriteLine(boxed); // {X=100, Y=0}
MethodInfo tt = temp.GetSetMethod();
tt.Invoke(boxed, new object[] { 200 });
Console.WriteLine(boxed); // {X=200, Y=0}
```

Note that this *won't* change the value of `p`, but you can unbox it again afterwards:

```
object boxed = p;
property.SetValue(boxed, ...);
p = (Point) boxed;
```

Comment: Or you can use `RuntimeHelpers.GetObjectValue(p)` to control boxing when calling `SetValue`

Comment: @KonradKokosa: Um, possibly :) Can't say I've used that myself, and I'm not sure how it would be useful here...

Answer (score 2):

Point is a struct, not a class. Its a value type and its passed by value. So when you pass point to `SetValue` method, copy of point is passed. That's why original instance `p` is not updated.

Suggested reading: [Value and Reference Types](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4d43ts61%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)